# Java RSA decrypting - Get rid of padded values

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, padding

I have a question about Decrypting messages using RSA algorithm.

I Use PKCS1Padding.

I encode string for example "MyTestString", but when Decoding I get "MyTestString"+ lot of  values

Of course I know that these  values are zero's added by padding algorithm and It's ok like that.

But I thought that decryption mechanism will get rid of these zero's and will return my plain text.

Am I missing something important or my assumptions were wrong?

Here is my code responsible for encoding and decoding.
Note : I'm dividing plain text in to equal length blocks and each of them is encrypted/decrypted separately and then glued/divided together

( keyMode is 1024 )
**CODE USED FOR ENCRYPTION**

```
byteArrayMessage = plainMessage.getBytes(ENCODING);
int keySize = keyMode;
int maxBlockSize = (keySize / 8 - 11);
int blocksCount = (int) Math.ceil((double) byteArrayMessage.length / maxBlockSize);
byte[][] blocksCollection = new byte[blocksCount][];
KeyFactory kf = null;
X509EncodedKeySpec pubSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(ConvertData.hexStringToByteArray(hexPubliKey));
PublicKey pubKey = null;
kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
pubKey = kf.generatePublic(pubSpec);
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

// encoding
        byte[] encrypted = null;
        int i = 0;
        int startIndex;
        int endIndex;
        int sizeOfBlocks = 0;
        while (i < blocksCount) {
            startIndex = i * (maxBlockSize);
            endIndex = startIndex + maxBlockSize;
            try {
                encrypted = cipher.doFinal((Arrays.copyOfRange(byteArrayMessage, startIndex, endIndex)));
                sizeOfBlocks += encrypted.length;
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            blocksCollection[i] = encrypted;
            i++;
        }


        i = 0;
        int n = blocksCollection.length;
        String gluedEncodedData = "";
        String encodedChunk;
        while (i < n) {
            encodedChunk = (ConvertData.byteArrayToHexString(blocksCollection[i]));
            gluedEncodedData += encodedChunk;
            i++;
        }
        Logger.trace("Glued Encoded data " + gluedEncodedData);
        return gluedEncodedData;
```

**CODE USED FOR DECRYPTION**

```
  PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(ConvertData.hexStringToByteArray(hexPrivateKey));
        KeyFactory kf;
        PrivateKey privateKey;
        Cipher cipher;
        kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(privSpec);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        byte[] encryptedBytes = ConvertData.hexStringToByteArray(hexEncodedData);
        int keySize = keyMode;
        int blockSize = (keySize / 8);

        int blocksCount = encryptedBytes.length / blockSize;
        int i = 0;
        int n = blocksCount;
        int startIndex;
        int endIndex;
        byte[] byteChunkData;
        byte[] decryptedChunk;
        byte[] decryptedMessage = new byte[0];
        while (i < n) {
            startIndex = i * (blockSize);
            endIndex = startIndex + blockSize;
            byteChunkData = Arrays.copyOfRange(encryptedBytes, startIndex, endIndex);
            decryptedChunk = cipher.doFinal(byteChunkData);
            decryptedMessage = concatenateByteArrays(decryptedMessage, decryptedChunk);
            i++;
        }
        String plainText = new String(decryptedMessage, ENCODING);
        return plainText;
```

Comment: I don't recognize what library you are using (I don't do crypto), but it looks pretty low-level.  Are you sure that it is not _your_ responsibility at that level to know where the message ends and the padding begins?  (E.g., you could use the first couple of bytes in the encrypted block to encode the length of the meaningful bytes.)

Comment: You may be right. If I remember correctly there was kind of padding that could indicate it's length by padded values. Could you please tell me if I should convert my output to String, search replace zero's to blank string ("") or is there way to trim bytearray before that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct problem is the following line during encryption:

```
encrypted = cipher.doFinal((Arrays.copyOfRange(byteArrayMessage, startIndex, endIndex)));
```

as the endIndex can be larger than the size of the array. So you should use the minimum of the `endIndex` and the actual size of the array.

You should however use a hybrid cryptosystem (mixing AES and RSA) instead. Note that just concatenating RSA encryption has many drawbacks such as high CPU usage and a larger ciphertext overhead, and does not provide you with integrity. Also note that it is a good idea to use OAEP encryption instead of PKCS#1 compatible encryption.

Comment: There is more hints that can be given, but I'll leave it at this if you don't mind.

Comment: At first I was gonna to argue with you that copyOfRange can't rise an error because endIndex can be outsiede of copied array. But I "meditated" on this one line of code long enough and enlightenment came from heaven :). Of course problem was with all the zero's added not by padding but by myself. I've changed last parameter to Math.min(byteArrayMessage.length,endIndex) and it works now. So answer is : yes, padding is automaticly getting rid of. Thank you very much :). I'll check OAEP of course.